# Bluemix のコンテナーイメージを選択するとエラーがで先に進まない

Tags: bluemix

Bluemix のコンテナーを使おうと思って、ダッシュボードから「コンテナーの開始」で開いたページでどのコンテナー・イメージをクリックしても次のエラーが出ます。原因がわかる方いらっしゃいますか？

エラーメッセージ

> コンテナー名前空間の取得
>   BXNUI0517E: The attempt to retrieve the container namespace of the org failed because of an internal error with incident ID 8cce4449350b112b. Try again later. If this problem continues, go to Support. For other help options, see the Bluemix Docs.

このメッセージ中の incident ID の内容を詳しく見てみたいとも思ったのですが、どこで見られるのかもよくわかりませんでした。こちらもご存知の方がいれば教えてください。

念のため申し上げておきますが、コンテナーには何も作っていない状態です。(コンテナー以外も何もありません）

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#messages/bxnui.html から調べますと、

> BXNUI0517E
>
> The container namespace of the org wasn't retrieved because of an internal error with incident ID incidentID.
>
> Try again later. If the problem continues, click the Account and Support icon in the top menu bar, click Get help, and search for help or get support.

時間をおいてもう一度試行するか、上部メニューバーにある[Account and Support]をクリックして、[Get Help]をクリックし、ヘルプを検索するか、サポートに問い合わせてください、のようですね。

Comment: 時間をおいて、というのが・・・日本時間 2015/12/16 16:00 頃から、2015/12/17 10:30 頃にかけて、数十回試しているのですが、状況が全く変わりません。これくらいの時間の開け方じゃ短いんでしょうか。
またヘルプの検索はすでに試したのですが有力な情報は得られませんでした。サポートへの問い合わせを日本語で出したのですが、今は英語でないと受け付けないという事でクローズされてしまい、 その後英語でサポートへの問い合わせはしてみていますが、まだ返答を得られていない状況です。

Comment: サポート側でインシデントIDを管理しているとは思いますが、1日経過しても一向に改善されないのを見ると困ったものですね・・・。一度試した時はそういったことはなかったのですが。。

Comment: 同様の問題を私も確認しました。先ほど、私も英語のSupport Centerに問い合わせをしてみましたので、返答が来次第、共有させていただきます。

Comment: 共有遅くなりました。12/21当日にサポートセンターから連絡があり、「Quata」（資源の割当量）の問題とのことで、他にも同様の問題が報告されており、対応中とのことでした。

現在、ＩＢＭ　Ｃｏｎｔａｉｎｔｅｒｓにアクセスしてみたところ、問題は解消されているようです！